# What is the best logic to find max version in HiveQL?

Tags: max, version, hiveql

I have the data in Hive table as below for Mobile Number and App Version number, and I wanted to get Max App Version Number installed in that mobile:

> select * from app_ver_test;

```
1112223333      1.1.1.10
1112223333      1.1.1.8
1112224444      1.1.1.15
1112224444      2.1.1.0
1112225555      5.1.1.8
1112225555      5.1.1.20
1112226666      5.1.1.20
```

when you select `simple max(App_ver)` with `group by mobile number`, then I am getting wrong results for 1112223333 as it is showing 1.1.1.8 instead of 1.1.1.10.
So Please help me here.
Thanks
Sateesh

```
select ctn,max(CONCAT_WS('0',(split(app_ver, '\\.'))))  from localytics.app_ver_test group by ctn;
select ctn,max(cast(CONCAT_WS('',(split(app_ver, '\\.'))) as Int)  from localytics.app_ver_test group by ctn;
select ctn,(cast(CONCAT_WS('',(split(app_ver, '\\.'))) as float))  from localytics.app_ver_test order by ctn
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select a.app_ver,ctn
FROM temp.test_table a
INNER JOIN (
select app_ver, (cast(max(cast(regexp_replace(ctn, "\\.", "")as int )) as string)) as max_value
from temp.test_table
group by app_ver) b 
ON a.app_ver=b.app_ver
and regexp_replace(a.ctn, "\\.", "")=b.max_value ;
```

Result:

```
+-------------+-----------+--+
|  a.app_ver  |    ctn    |
+-------------+-----------+--+
| 1112223333  | 1.1.1.10  |
| 1112224444  | 1.1.1.15  |
| 1112225555  | 5.1.1.20  |
| 1112226666  | 5.1.1.20  |
+-------------+-----------+--+
```

Comment: Thank you Mariyanova and it worked out for the given samples, but I have one more example which will gives wrong results. For Eg: if CTN/Version No - 1.1.80 and 2.1, here 2.1 should be maximum but with our query, will get 1.1.80, so I need to take care this as well..please try , even I will check today. Thanks in Advance and nice weekend.. Regards, Sateesh